# Finding other network player unity unet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I am having problem in getting other network player
I want to store like this.

```
void Start ()
{
    GameObject[] players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player");
    for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++) {
        if (players [i].GetComponent <NetworkIdentity> ().isLocalPlayer) {
            minePlayer = players [i];
        }
        if (!players [i].GetComponent <NetworkIdentity> ().isLocalPlayer) {
            oppenentPlayer = players [i];
        }
    }
}
```

in server i only find mine player and in other player i find both but not correctly
advance thanks for your help

Comment: @sudoman281 Kindly Help me about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title of your question and your code assumes there are only two players in Unity game. There can be up to 10 players in the game and you should also handle them. You need to find the players from `PlayerController` and this can be retrieved with `NetworkManager.client.connection.playerControllers`. You also have to check `IsValid` to make sure that the `PlayerController` has a Player attached to it.

Below is how you can find all the players on the network:

```
NetworkManager networkManager = NetworkManager.singleton;

List<PlayerController> pc = networkManager.client.connection.playerControllers;

for (int i = 0; i < pc.Count; i++)
{

    if (pc[i].IsValid)
        Debug.Log(pc[i].gameObject.name);
}
```

Comment: there are only 2 players no more then 2 can b in the game and thanks for help

Comment: It doesn't matter how many players. It should still work. Get the first two `IsValid` objects then `break` out of the loop.